# Non-equivalent variables evaluating as equal in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, equality

So while testing some code I discovered some odd functionality in Python, namely two variables with different values evaluating as equal. The code that produces said behavior is as follows

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3]
        self.y = self.x

    def ChangeX(self):
        self.x.append(4)

    def equals(self):
        print(self.x==self.y)
```

When I run this code the variables initialize as they should and such. If I run

```
f = Foo()
f.equals()
```

The output is True, which I can understand because both f.x and f.y hold the same value at this point. However, when I run

```
r = Foo()
r.ChangeX()
r.equals()
```

The output is still true. This confuses me. r.x and r.y plainly do not hold the same values anymore (printing them in sequence even gives different outputs), and yet Python seems to believe that the two variables equal each other.

I have a hunch that this has to do with the fact that I'm using a class; however I still dont know what exactly is going on here or how to "fix" it. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.x` and `self.y` both reference the same list object in memory.  Meaning, when you update one, the other will reflect the change.

You can see this behavior in the below demonstration:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>>
>>> # The contents of a and b are the same
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> # And their ids are the same
>>> id(a)
33908856
>>> id(b)
33908856
>>>
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

---

If you want to change this behavior, you could assign `self.y` to a shallow copy of `self.x`:

```
self.y = self.x[:]
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>>
>>> # The contents of a and b are the same
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> # But their ids are different
>>> id(a)
33984680
>>> id(b)
33984960
>>>
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Could you explain why [this method](http://pastebin.com/QzSwyFsq) (it's only part of a larger class), when run, gives different id's for both "previous" and "self.Board"? Even though their id's are different, modifying "self.Board" still modifies "previous" after it has been assigned. This is the code which drove me to ask this question, and I can provide a full version if needed.

Comment: The code always says that "previous" and "self.Board" are equal even after only one has been modified, stopping at 0 iterations every time

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 - If I had to guess, `self.SpawnTile()` is not actually modifying `self.Board`.  So, when you get here `if self.Board == previous:`, the contents of `self.Board` and `previous` are the same.  Hence, they are treated as being equal, even though their ids are different.

Comment: I looked through the code, and it doesnt seem like `self.Board` was not being changed. Can you look at [the complete code and some sample output](http://pastebin.com/U2JdVUFj)? The code's not too long, otherwise I wouldnt ask you to do this

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 - Oh, I did not know that `self.Board` was a list of _lists_ (i.e. mutable containers).  In that case, you cannot use a shallow copy because it will not copy the sub-lists.  Instead, `previous` will be a new list of _references_ to the sub-lists in `self.Board`.  To fix the problem, import the `deepcopy` function from the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module and then do `previous = deepcopy(self.Board)`.  That should work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have two lists. You have a list `x` and a reference to list `x` called list `y`. When you modify your list x, the value behind the reference y is also modified. Read more about this [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`self.x` and `self.y` refer to the same data. When you do

```
self.y = self.x
```

you bind both variables to the same array in memory.

Better to do this if you want them to be distinct

```
self.y = list(self.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `self.y = self.x` is just assigning to `y` a reference to `x`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3]
        self.y = self.x

    def ChangeX(self):
        self.x.append(4)

    def equals(self):
        print(self.x==self.y)


f = Foo()
f.equals()
f.ChangeX()
f.equals()
print(f.x)
print(f.y)
#True
#True
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
```